# Load environment variables when running locally via serverless offline

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

I want to load env variables from .env file, when running locally,
So here's my serverless.yaml file,

```
functions:
  health:
    handler: src/api/health.check
    name: ${self:provider.stackName}-health
    environment:
      USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID: !Ref UserPoolClient
```

You see, it sets a userpool id that gets created in the resources section as an environment variable to a lambda. This works perfectly fine, when deployed as expected.

However, when I try to run it locally via serverless-offline, no matter how I set the env variables, via dotenv or manually, it seems to get overriden by serverless, in this case all I see is "[object object]".

Other workflows that I see, load all env variables from files, like below

```
functions:
  health:
    handler: src/api/health.check
    name: ${self:provider.stackName}-health
    environment:
      USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID: {env:USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID}
```

But wouldn't this require us to have variables of all stages, stored locally as files?

I was hoping to store only the dev version, locally, and have all the remaining fetched from the serverless file itself, automatically via `!Ref` like shown at the beginning.

So, how do I prevent, serverless from populating/polluting my env variables when I run locally, while sticking to the first format?

Or are there other better ways to handle this?

Comment: What version of Serverless Framework are you using? In v3 there are stage parameters, that can be used to set different values for different stages: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/parameters#stage-parameters

Answer (score 0):

It happened here with the new version of serverless-offline (v12.0.4).

My solution was to use: https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse

See the example below:

```
serverlessIfElse:
- If: '"${env:NODE_ENV}" == "development"'
  Set:
    functions.health.environment.USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID: "${env:USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID, ''}"
```

You can change it for your use case.